# Insulating and leveling sunroom floors

Tags: insulation, flooring, old-house, leveling, sunroom

We have an old, 1911 house in Minnesota. Our front room is a converted porch which is drafty and quite sloped. Our plan is to rip up the old linoleum floors, get down to the joists, and essentially rebuild the floor to be level with the rest of the house.

My question is about insulation. The room doesn't have crawlspace access, and since we are taking up the floor we want to insulate the floor to help keep out that cold Minnesota winter. We plan to put down a vapor barrier, but aren't sure what insulation to use. We would like to stay away from fiber and opt for something more environmentally friendly. What insulation should we use? And any tips for leveling and insulating floors when you don't have crawlspace access?

Comment: While you have the floor out consider adding hydronic heat. I did that over 15 years ago, we love it and it works great. Be sure to run the calculations for your boiler temperature. I used potable water for mine and a hot water heater. It does not have the higher temperature of a boiler. In the summer we circulate cold water and it makes a big difference.

Comment: Hi and welcome to DIY. So you have joists but no crawlspace? What's under the joists? What are you environmental concerns with fibre? Do you mean fibreglass? Is XPS an environmental option? How are the walls and ceiling insulated?

Comment: Every form of insulation is going to come with some sort of "environmental concern". What are the _specific_ things you want to avoid?